# Specifying a tabular of a certain shape as a new command

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, framed

I have such tables in many places of my document:

```
My table is $ R = \raisebox{1.5ex}{{\begin{tabular}{lll}
\textit{x}             & \textit{y}             &   \\ \cline{1-2}
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{a} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{A} & 1 \\
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{a} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{B} & 2 \\
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{b} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{C} & 4 \\
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{b} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{D} & 7 \\ \cline{1-2}
\end{tabular}}} $
```

[image]

It is an inlined table, which contents are framed, while a header (a first row) and a last column are both standing out like in the picture above. Header is in italics.

The `tabular` itself is raised `1.5ex` in order to align only the framed box to a baseline, but not the whole table. So that, in the picture, `=` is at a center of a frame. (This is probably not the best way of doing it, as it corelates with font sizing, but I don't find any better way so far).

I want to specify this `tabular` as a command, where I only pass `(x,y)` (the header) and `(a,A,1),(a,B,2),(b,C,4),(b,D,7)` (the contents), without specifying any of alignment and formatting.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done with stacks, using inline macro

```
\mystack{<table content>}{<column labels>}{<row labels>}
```

The table is set in text mode, whereas the labels are set in math mode.  This macro can handle arbitrary dimensions.

**REVISED ANSWER** (handles column data of arbitrary width)

This uses the nice `tabstackengine` feature that the cell dimensions of the most recently created stack are saved and accessible via `\TABwd{<column>}`, `\TABht{<row>}` and `\TABdp{<row>}`.  Thus, the boxed matrix can be stacked, and its column-width dimensions are available for creating the column-labels of the proper width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine,listofitems}
\setstacktabbedgap{\tabcolsep}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\mystack[3]{%
  \savestack\mydata{\tabbedCenterstack{#1}}%
  \setsepchar{&}%
  \readlist\mycollabels{#2}%
  \def\collabelstack{}%
  \foreachitem\x\in\mycollabels{%
    \ifnum\xcnt>1\relax\g@addto@macro\collabelstack{&}\fi%
    \expandafter\protected@edef\expandafter\collabelstack\expandafter{%
      \collabelstack\makebox[\TABwd{\xcnt}]{$\x$}}%
  }%
  \stackon{\fbox{\mydata}}{\expandafter\Matrixstack\expandafter{\collabelstack}}%
    \hspace{\tabcolsep}%
  \Vectorstack{#3}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
My table is $R = \mystack{a&AAA&t\\a&B&z\\b&C&qq\\b&D&r}{x&y&z}{1\\2\\4\\7}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ORIGINAL ANSWER** (assumes column data of uniform width)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\setstacktabbedgap{2\tabcolsep}
\newcommand\mystack[3]{%
  \stackon{\fbox{\tabbedCenterstack{#1}}}{\Matrixstack{#2}}\hspace{\tabcolsep}%
  \Vectorstack{#3}%
}
\begin{document}
My table is $R = \mystack{a&A\\a&B\\b&C\\b&D}{x&y}{1\\2\\4\\7}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) ...`tabstackengine` is really powerful and enable generalized solution as OP wish ..

Comment: I wonder how to make all spacings more compact and even, like this:
http://imgur.com/a/CQIho ?

Comment: There is a little problem — the top line is column-wise misaligned with the boxed content: http://imgur.com/a/MhCxl. How should one deal with this?

Comment: @dan31 As to the compactness, the intercolumn gap is defined via `\setstacktabbedgap{2\tabcolsep}`

Comment: @dan31 As to the second point on column alignment, please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can center your table without specifying `\raisebox[1.5ex]{..}` by simply using `\phantom` for the header and adding it as an extra row. The following new command accepts the header elements as two arguments and the rest of the table as a third argument. I also removed the need for `multicolumn` in the table body to be more readable.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\ctabular}[3]{\begin{tabular}{|ll|l}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textit{#1}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textit{#2}} & \\ \cline{1-2}
#3 \\ \cline{1-2}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\phantom{\textit{#1}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\phantom{\textit{#2}}}  & 
\end{tabular}
}

My table is $ R = \ctabular{x}{y}{
a & A & 1 \\
a & B & 2 \\
b & C & 4 \\
b & D & 7} $

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thanks @AboAmmar! How is that possible to generalize `\ctabular` to arbitrary dimentions? E.g.

    My table is $ R = \ctabular{x}{y}{z}{
    a & A & n & 1 \\
    a & B & m & 2 \\
    b & C & q & 4 \\
    b & D & t & 7} $

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand{\mcl}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{#1}}
\newcommand\carray[3]{\raisebox{1.5ex}{\begin{tabular}{|ll|l}
                                        \mcl{$#1$}   & \mcl{$#2$} & \\ \cline{1-2}
                                        #3                          \\  \cline{1-2}
                                       \end{tabular}}
                     }

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum*[11]
My table is $ R = \carray{x}{y}{
                    a           & A         & 1 \\
                    a           & B         & 2 \\
                    b           & C         & 4 \\
                    b           & D         & 7 }$
\lipsum[11]
\end{document}
```

[image]

*note:*
such solutions doesn't spare a lot of typing :) and its generalization is not simple. also use such tables as inline element is not smart idea (see image above).

Comment: Agree on inlining @Zarko. Most of the time such tables will take part in block formulas (however being inlined within formulas, maybe in reduced font size).

Comment: @dan31, for inline you should look for `smallmatrix` or similar environments from `amsmath` package. they use smaller fonts.

Comment: `\bordermatrix` seems also related, but the amount of customization for it seems tremendous (make a box instead of matrix paranthesis, move a comment from the left side to the right and such — feels much like a new environment).

Comment: Your picture is out of sync with your code.  It shows the column labels in text, rather than math, mode.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, thank you to point this ... i didn't load the last version of my answer :(. now corrected.

Comment: huh, what of confusion :(, i load the last code but not the image. hopefully now is correct :)